# Github multiple account issue

Tags: git, ssh, github

When I try doing something like this:: 
git push git@github-client:antonyr/Spring-Hibernate.git 
I get something as following

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github-client:antonyr/Spring-Hibernate.git'
```

By the way I have set multiple accounts using SSH for github.com.

Please help.

Comment: "Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'."

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a branch to push. To push `master`:

```
$ git push git@github-client:antonyr/Spring-Hibernate.git master
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Currently logged in SSH account is user abc. now I want to use another account on github.com called antonyr

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command before pushing to git 
$ git push origin master

it should work.